# Generate ID for mapped item

Tags: java, spring-boot, mapstruct

On our project, it's customary to use mapstruct for all mappings. In this unique case, I'm not creating an Entity, but rather a DTO. However this DTO requires I generate a UUID, and I'd rather not use the expression option.

```
@Mapping(target = "trackId", expression = "java(UUID.randomUUID().toString())")
FileUploadRequest inventoryToFileUpload(Inventory inventory);
```

I'd much rather have the compiler as a friend at all times in life. Also what do you do if the generation strategy isn't a 30 character width one-liner?

My preferred method is as follows:

```
@Mapping(target = "trackId", qualifiedByName = "generateUUID"),
FileUploadRequest inventoryToFileUpload(Inventory inventory);


@Named("generateUUID")
default String generateUuid() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

Sadly the above does not work. I have to give it a source, which is nonsense. Or maybe there's a way of specifying I don't rely on any parameter?

Here is code that does work:

```
// Ommiting other mappings for clarity
@Mapping(target = "trackId", source = "id", qualifiedByName = "generateUUID")
FileUploadRequest inventoryToFileUpload(Inventory inventory);

@Named("generateUUID")
default String generateUuid(final String nonsense) {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

This generates the following line of code

```
fileUploadRequest.setTrackId(this.generateUuid(inventory.getId()));
```

But ... the parameter is superflous, as can easily be seen. I know that this does not ***ACTUALLY*** matter. But it seems either like an oversight, or me not understanding how to declare that I do not have a source for this, I just want the mapper to call my method.

Again, `expression` is not a valid answer, please do not propose it. UNLESS you can do `expression = "java(generateUuid())"`?

Comment: "*I'd much rather have the compiler as a friend at all times in life.*" - Even with the expression, you have the compiler by your side. MapStruct writes .java files, which are then compiled by the compiler. If you were to have a syntax error in the expression, you would get a compilation error.

Comment: Still, I did mention the usecase of having long code. Several lines maybe? What if I just want to call a method and nothing else?

Comment: this can - as far as I know - done through an `expression`, coupled with a `default` method as well.

Comment: did you try to override hashCode function of your class?

Comment: "*Again, `expression` is not a valid answer, please do not propose it. UNLESS you can do `expression = "java(generateUuid())"`?*" - Why not try it out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MapStruct is about mapping between different objects. That's why you can't use an empty method (without `expression`).

What I would suggest is to indeed use `Mapping#expression`. However, to simplify it for you, you can use something like:

```
public class MappingUtils {

    public static String GENERATE_UUID_EXPRESSION = "java(<package>.MappingUtils.generateUuid())"


    public static String generateUuid() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

}
```

And then in your mappers you can do:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "trackId", expression = MappingUtils. GENERATE_UUID_EXPRESSION)
    FileUploadRequest inventoryToFileUpload(Inventory inventory);

}
```

Doing this you have the expression in a single place and you have a a method that performs the generation.

The generated code will use the full qualified name of the `MappingUtils`. In case you want to avoid that you will need to add `MappingUtils` to `Mapper#imports` and then use `MappingUtils.class.getName()` instead in your expression.

Note: You'll need to replace what is in `<package>` with the package location of the `MappingUtils`.

Comment: this gives me error that Attribute value must be constant in mapper class expression

Comment: You are right @Loren. I've edited the answer to have a valid code.